# how to fix FIxed effect model?

Tags: python, model, regression

"The index on the time dimension must be either numeric or date-like" This mistake appears when i try to set up fixed effect within model and random effect model.

Ive got a panel data which contain year price cost and such numerical-only variables.

import pandas as pd
from linearmodels.panel import PanelOLS

df = pd.DataFrame()

within_model = PanelOLS.from_formula('cost ~ RPM + price + load + EntityEffects', data=df)
result = within_model.fit()

print(result)

Answer (score -1):

seems like the error "The index on the time dimension must be either numeric or date-like" in `linearmodels` indicates an issue with the time dimension. Here are quick steps:

1. **Check Time Format:**

   - Ensure your time variable is in a numeric or date-like format.

   ```py
   # If using dates, convert to datetime format
   df['date_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_column'])
   ```
2. **Set Multi-level Index:**

   - Set a multi-level index with entity and time dimensions.

   ```py
   df = df.set_index(['entity_column', 'date_column'])
   ```
3. **Specify Entity and Time Columns:**

   - Ensure correct entity and time columns in the formula.

   ```py
   within_model = PanelOLS.from_formula('cost ~ RPM + price + load + EntityEffects', data=df)
   ```
4. **Consider `time_effects` Option:**

   - If time is in date format, use `time_effects=True`.

   ```py
   within_model = PanelOLS.from_formula('cost ~ RPM + price + load + EntityEffects', data=df, time_effects=True)
   ```

Replace 'entity_column' and 'date_column' with your actual entity and time column names. If the issue persists, share a sample dataset or more details for further assistance

check https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/